# Recurrent Neural Network with multiple output sequences of different length

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

So I am using `tensorflow 2` and  trying to predict many sequences of differing lengths from one sequence of a fixed length. Specifically, the input sequence have a fixed length of 31 and I want to predict 15 sequences where the first 5 sequences have one length (for example 10), the next 5 have another length (for example 21) and the last 5 have a sequence length of 30 (input_length-1).

I guess I have to use padding before the output layer such that all values larger than desired sequence length are zero for all training examples. Some help would be greatly appreciated since i am quite stuck atm...

Bellow follows a minimal example to illustrate what i want to do

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# examples of parameters for archictecture
neurons = 50
nb_features = 1
maximum_sequence_length = 31
nb_sequences = 15
# Here are the desired sequence lengths of output
length_of_first_5_seqs = 10
length_of_5_to_10_seqs = 21
length_of_last_5_seqs = maximum_sequence_length-1
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(neurons,
                            input_shape = (maximum_sequence_length, nb_features)))
# RepeaterVector layer in order to produce outputs of maximum_sequence_length -1
model.add(tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(maximum_sequence_length-1))
# add LSTM enable return sequences
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(neurons, return_sequences = True))
# Here i guess i should do something
# output layer
model.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(nb_features* nb_sequences)))

model.summary()

# fictional data
data = np.random.rand(100, maximum_sequence_length, nb_features)
yhat = model(data, training = False)
```

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 50)                10400     
_________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector (RepeatVector) (None, 30, 50)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 30, 50)            20200     
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistri (None, 30, 15)            765       
=================================================================
Total params: 31,365
Trainable params: 31,365
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps easier to solve using the functional API

```
inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (maximum_sequence_length, nb_features))
X = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(neurons, return_sequences = False)(inp)
T1 = tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(length_of_first_5_seqs-1)(X)
T2 = tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(length_of_5_to_10_seqs-1)(X)
T3 = tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(length_of_last_5_seqs-1)(X)
T1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(neurons, return_sequences = True)(T1)
T2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(neurons, return_sequences = True)(T2)
T3 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(neurons, return_sequences = True)(T3)
T1 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(nb_features))(T1)
T2 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(nb_features))(T2)
T3 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(nb_features))(T3)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = inp, outputs = [T1, T2, T3])
```